# nginx duplicate location "/" error

Tags: nginx

I want to redirect to https when scheme is http and location is /

```
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     bla;

    location / {
        return 301 https://bla;
    }

    include fs.inc;
}
```

Now, problem is: fs.inc includes anothes "location /" and even if this is never called the nginx configuration test fails with error `duplicate location "/" in fs.inc:1`.

How can I solve that?

Comment: `location = /` mean exact match, not prefix

Answer (score 1):

You need another server block:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name bla; # make sure this is the same

    # add your ssl specific directives here

    location / {
        alias /var/www/secured/;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name bla;

    return 301 https://$request_uri;
}
```

This is a global redirect

Comment: hm, but I only want to redirect to https when location is only /, not more

Comment: are you saying if the link is /hello you want it http? but if it's / you want to redirect to https? what if someone bookmarked /hello?